# how i just extract the link for class = main-bullet using web craweling

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, scrapy

i used this and using this i will extract all the in the web page but i want specific link which are in the main-bullet class.

```
import requests
import bs4
res = requests.get('http://www.hindisamay.com/writer/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9E%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AF.cspx?id=1275&name=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9E%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AF')
print(res)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
h = soup.select('title')
print(h)
    #got all link of the website
all_links = soup.find_all("a")
for link in all_links:
    link.get("href")
    print(link.get("href"))
```

I used this give all the links...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.xpath()` method. For example, the code below returns a list with all links extracted under the "main-bullet" class.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
response = requests.get('http://www.hindisamay.com/writer/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9E%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AF.cspx?id=1275&name=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9E%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AF')
response_html = html.fromstring(response.content.decode('utf8'))
links = response_html.xpath('//ul[contains(@class,"main-bullet")]//a/@href')
links
```

Comment: . itshow like this    'http://www.hindisamay.com/content/714/1/à¤\x85à¤\x9cà¥\x8dà¤\x9eà¥\x87à¤¯-à¤\x95à¤µà¤¿à¤¤à¤¾à¤\x8fà¤\x81-à¤\x9aà¥\x81à¤¨à¥\x80-à¤¹à¥\x81à¤\x88-à¤\x95à¤µà¤¿à¤¤à¤¾à¤\x8fà¤\x81.cspx ', 'http://www.hindisamay.com/content/499/1/à¤\x85à¤\x9cà¥\x8dà¤\x9eà¥\x87à¤¯-à¤¨à¤¾à¤\x9fà¤\x95-à¤\x89à¤¤à¥\x8dà¤¤à¤°-à¤ªà¥\x8dà¤°à¤¿à¤¯à¤¦à¤°à¥\x8dà¤¶à¥\x80.cspx ', 'http://www.hindisamay.com/content/493/1/à¤\x85à¤\x9cà¥\x8dà¤\x9eà¥\x87à¤¯-

Comment: In this case, is necessary to decode the response of the request (see the updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

To extract all links under `main-bullet` class, you can use `.select()` method.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.hindisamay.com/writer/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9E%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AF.cspx?id=1275&name=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9E%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AF'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('.main-bullet a'):
    print(a.get_text(strip=True), a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
चुनी हुई कविताएँ http://www.hindisamay.com/content/714/1/अज्ञेय-कविताएँ-चुनी-हुई-कविताएँ.cspx 
उत्तर प्रियदर्शी http://www.hindisamay.com/content/499/1/अज्ञेय-नाटक-उत्तर-प्रियदर्शी.cspx 
वसंत का अग्रदूत http://www.hindisamay.com/content/493/1/अज्ञेय-संस्मरण-वसंत-का-अग्रदूत.cspx 
संवाद http://www.hindisamay.com/content/521/1/अज्ञेय-संस्मरण-संवाद.cspx 
‘अज्ञेय’ : अपनी निगाह में http://www.hindisamay.com/content/496/1/अज्ञेय-आत्मकथा-अज्ञेय-अपनी-निगाह-में.cspx 
ऋण-स्वीकारी हूँ http://www.hindisamay.com/content/495/1/अज्ञेय-आत्मकथा-ऋण-स्वीकारी-हूँ.cspx 
कला का स्वाभाव और उद्देश्य http://www.hindisamay.com/content/6777/1/अज्ञेय-निबंध-कला-का-स्वाभाव-और-उद्देश्य.cspx 
कविता : श्रव्य से पाठ्य तक http://www.hindisamay.com/content/2000/1/अज्ञेय-निबंध-कविता-श्रव्य-से-पाठ्य-तक.cspx 
काल का डमरु-नाद http://www.hindisamay.com/content/2001/1/अज्ञेय-निबंध-काल-का-डमरु-नाद.cspx 
छाया का जंगल http://www.hindisamay.com/content/2009/1/अज्ञेय-निबंध-छाया-का-जंगल.cspx 
ताली तो छूट गयी http://www.hindisamay.com/content/2007/1/अज्ञेय-निबंध-ताली-तो-छूट-गयी.cspx 
नई कविता : प्रयोग के आयाम http://www.hindisamay.com/content/2004/1/अज्ञेय-निबंध-नई-कविता-प्रयोग-के-आयाम.cspx 
भारतीयता http://www.hindisamay.com/content/6775/1/अज्ञेय-निबंध-भारतीयता.cspx 
मरुथल की सीपियाँ http://www.hindisamay.com/content/2008/1/अज्ञेय-निबंध-मरुथल-की-सीपियाँ.cspx 
रूढ़ि और मौलिकता http://www.hindisamay.com/content/6778/1/अज्ञेय-निबंध-रूढ़ि-और-मौलिकता.cspx 
वैज्ञानिक सत्ता, मिथकीय सत्ता और कवि http://www.hindisamay.com/content/1999/1/अज्ञेय-निबंध-वैज्ञानिक-सत्ता-मिथकीय-सत्ता-और-कवि.cspx 
वासुदेव प्याला http://www.hindisamay.com/content/4299/1/अज्ञेय-निबंध-वासुदेव-प्याला.cspx 
शब्द, मौन, अस्तित्व http://www.hindisamay.com/content/2005/1/अज्ञेय-निबंध-शब्द-मौन-अस्तित्व.cspx 
स्मृति और काल http://www.hindisamay.com/content/2002/1/अज्ञेय-निबंध-स्मृति-और-काल.cspx 

... and so on.
```

---

EDIT (to save to csv):

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.hindisamay.com/writer/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9E%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AF.cspx?id=1275&name=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9E%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AF'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for a in soup.select('.main-bullet a'):
    all_data.append([a.get_text(strip=True), a['href']])

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in all_data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

This produces `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, if I want this data in CSV formate name and link so how can I do, if u suggest it will help

Comment: thank u its works but the names are showing like symbol esample- à¤šà¥à¤¨à¥€ à¤¹à¥à¤ˆ à¤•à¤µà¤¿à¤¤à¤¾à¤à¤

Answer (score -1):

you know xpath？[XPath](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

```
//*[@class="xxx"]
```

Comment: Really, @xionz is that how you answer Q's?